# How to display an Image in fullscreen?

Tags: java-me

I want to display an Image in fullscreen. How to achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for displaying an image in full screen you need to use Game Canvas.

Comment: Ok , I used LWUIT. I created a LWUIT Form class and in its paint methdod I use the drawImage method of the graphics parameter. The image I draw is created so that its width and height are those of the LWUIT Form. Nevertheless thanks for your response.